# DA 40 NG - Diesel option OAM 40-370

Tags: diamond-da40

Diamond DA-40 NG Manual did say that to use Auto Diesel (EN590), OAM 40-370 must be installed. Does anybody know or have experience on this OAM 40-370 requirement?
I cannot find this document on the Diamond Website

Comment: what exactly do you need help with? as it stands your question is a bit vague and we cannot really help you.

Comment: OAM 40-370 is a STC, I think the OP is asking what modifications are required for auto diesel @Federico.

Comment: @GdD or they could be asking where to find the text describing this OAM [I cannot find], or they might be asking who can do the modifications [does anyone have experience]

Answer (score 1):

You can easily find this out for yourself by searching on the OAM.
This leads to Diamond Aircraft service bulletins relating to the change.

[Work instruction](http://support.diamond-air.at/fileadmin/uploads/files/after_sales_support/DA40%20New%20Generation/Service_Bulletins/SB40NG-030-O-0-Provisions-for-Operation-with-Diesel-fuel-incl-WI.pdf)

[AFM](http://support.diamond-air.at/fileadmin/uploads/files/after_sales_support/DA40%20New%20Generation/Airplane_Flight_Manual/Basic_Manual/60115e-DA40-NG-AFM-r3-complete.pdf)

[Software notice](http://support.diamond-air.at/fileadmin/uploads/files/after_sales_support/DA40%20New%20Generation/Service_Bulletins/SB40NG-002-12-M-Software-for-E4A-Engine.pdf)

Looks from these that it requires 3 things:
2 placards relating to the different engine operation temperatures, and potentially a software upgrade to the engine management system (depending on the version currently installed).

Comment: According to the work instruction, you also need to install check valves if they are not already installed.

Comment: Thank you all for the assistance. I got info from Diamond that OAM 40-370 is factory document.

Comment: @AbdRazakMohamadzin you're welcome. Glad I could help. Blue side up and have fun.